# Is there anything else to std::cbegin() other than begin()ing a const reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I'm constrained to writing C++11 code, but I want to use `std::cbegin()`. So, I'm looking at GCC 5.4.0's implementation, in `/usr/include/c++/5/bits/range_access.h` on my system, thinking I might write something similar, and I see:

```
  template<class _Container>
    inline constexpr auto
    cbegin(const _Container& __cont) noexcept(noexcept(std::begin(__cont)))
      -> decltype(std::begin(__cont))
    { return std::begin(__cont); }
```

is that all there is to it? Am I missing something? If that's it, how come it wasn't part of C++11 like `std::begin()`?

Comment: As for why it wasn't part: Because you didn't write up the proposal in time. Shame on you :-)

Comment: I don't really understand the question. What other answer than "yes" do you expect?

Comment: One of the main reasons `std::begin/end` was added was so plain arrays (which don't have `begin/end` member functions) could be used in range-for loops. `std::cbegin/cend` was not necessary for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is that all there is to it?

Yes.

> Am I missing something?

Not that I'm aware of.

> If that's it, how come it wasn't part of C++11 like std::begin()?

The global templates seem to have been part of the original proposal as an alternative to the member functions, but the proposal preferred to only provide the member functions in favour of providing either just the global templates, or both the templates and members. (Assuming this is the original proposal: [N1674](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1674.pdf)).

The committee chose to include the member function alternative in C++11, and the template not until C++14. I'm not part of the committee, and cannot speak for them, but my guess is that the attitude of the proposal may have affected the decision:

> While this generic adapter alternative seems quite straightforward, we nonetheless favor the
>   member function approach as proposed above.  It seems more in keeping with current C++
>   programming idioms, such as the parallel use of
>   rbegin
>   as a container member function rather
>   than as a generic adapter

Here is the development for the C++ Standard Library Defect Report [issue (2128)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2128) where the template versions were decided to be adopted into C++14 after all.

Answer (score 0):

No, that covers it.

Although a small function can be added to the standard with a relatively small amount of effort, time is finite and the committee doesn't have unlimited resource. Another example of a reasonably useful and trivial function that was omitted until C++14 is `std::make_unique`. Things improve over time.